# How do I turn off the "Evaluating: plt.show() did not finish after 3.00s seconds." warning in the VsCode debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I often debug my python code by plotting NumPy arrays in the vscode debugger.
Often I spend more than 3s looking at a plot. When I do vscode prints the extremely
long warning below. It's very annoying because I then have to scroll up a lot
all the time to see previous debugging outputs. Where is this PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT
variable? How do I turn this off?

I included the warning below for completeness, thanks a lot for your help!

> Evaluating: plt.show() did not finish after 3.00s seconds.
> This may mean a number of things:
>
> - This evaluation is really slow and this is expected.
>   In this case it's possible to silence this error by raising the timeout, setting the
>   PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT environment variable to a bigger value.
> - The evaluation may need other threads running while it's running:
>   In this case, it's possible to set the PYDEVD_UNBLOCK_THREADS_TIMEOUT
>   environment variable so that if after a given timeout an evaluation doesn't finish,
>   other threads are unblocked or you can manually resume all threads.
>
>   Alternatively, it's also possible to skip breaking on a particular thread by setting a
>   `pydev_do_not_trace = True` attribute in the related threading.Thread instance
>   (if some thread should always be running and no breakpoints are expected to be hit in it).
> - The evaluation is deadlocked:
>   In this case you may set the PYDEVD_THREAD_DUMP_ON_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT
>   environment variable to true so that a thread dump is shown along with this message and
>   optionally, set the PYDEVD_INTERRUPT_THREAD_TIMEOUT to some value so that the debugger
>   tries to interrupt the evaluation (if possible) when this happens.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If found a way to adapt the launch.json which takes care of this problem.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {"DISPLAY":":1",
                    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT": "500"},
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: in case you are using the test debugger you can also add `"purpose": ["debug-test"],`

Comment: What's the unit here? What does 500 mean? 500s?

Comment: @CGFoX yes, it's seconds

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wanting to adjust it in the current session (e.g., because you've attached to a live process you don't want to restart) try this from the debug console.

```py
import _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants
_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants.PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT = 30. # seconds
```

[Reference](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/47300e090388fa74e0650bf8af93ea19ca8074ea/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py#L322)

Answer (score -1):

based on [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2752#issuecomment-471640985), you can simply set the timeout parameter of debug configuration(launch.json). for example, sth like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "timeout": 10,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are keen to surpress the warning, you'd go like this:

In this documentation, point 28.6.3, you can do so:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

Here's the code if the link dies in the future.

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

You should be ready to go with a simple copy paste.

Comment: Hi AEM, thanks for the swift reply ;-)! I already found this and am using a bare " import warnings;  warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  " in my main, but it does not get rid of the warning in the debugger.